# How to access members of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, object, member, accessor

In C++, vector works such that if I instantiate a vector, of type Obj for example, I can access the members of an Obj with the dot accessor by specifying the element.  I'm trying to do the same thing with a template `<class T> struct`.

How can I access the Obj members of a struct, a `template <class T> Struct` containing a `vector<T>` for example, instantiated as `Struct<Obj>`.

If I'm on the wrong track, what's the alternative?

Comment: Actual, *real*, class declarations for `Struct`, `Obj`, and anything containing vectors of said-same, as well as a simple accessor sample of what you're trying (but not succeeding) in doing, would do *wonders* in making this question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you have this:

```
struct Obj
{
    int x_;
};

template <typename T>
struct Struct
{
    std::vector<T> items_;
};
```

So to access an element (assuming you added it to the vector):

```
int main()
{
    Struct s;
    s.items_.resize(10);
    s.items_[0].x_ = 5; // Access the object memeber of element 0 in the vector.
}
```